# Adding Custom Elements to Flex Charts

Tags: apache-flex, charts, element

If you see google finance or other such charts, they usually have a small pentagon on the chart that indicates when the divident was paid.

[image]

note the **D** markers in the screenshot

http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:INTC
In this link you will see A,B,C,D .... along the charts X-Axis. 
If you choose a larger data range say 2005- 2010 , then you will see blue divident markers along the x-Axis.

Is there any thing in Flex that will allow us to do that ?
What is that feature known as?

Regards,
Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having access to their code, but understanding quite a bit about the Flex Charting components that you will find in the standard Flex SDK, I can say with almost complete certainty that the google finance charts are **not** using Flex Charting.

That said, you can extend the Flex charts and do some fairly powerful things. This includes custom markers.

> the truth is, that building a custom chart element is not necessarily a simple task. With power comes complexity, and to build even a simple chart extension, there’s a fair amount of learning to be done about how the journey is made from data values to pictures on the screen.

[Here is a great post about adding extra elements and layers to your charts.](http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/charts/easy-custom-charts/) The article is a bit older, but the Flex Charts haven't changed much since it was written. It should give a basic idea about what it takes to start customizing your charts.

Comment: Thank you Joel, I see a few things in the link that closely match my needs . Reading the article now...